# Changing "realpath" utility on macOS Ventura

Tags: ventura

I have a build system that relies on the "realpath" utility. However, after upgrading to Ventura, a new "realpath" was added to /bin and, unfortunately, it doesn't support the option my build system uses (--s). Is it possible to change the order of how utilities are found in the path or to change /bin/realpath to point to the one that works? I looked into disabling the SIP, but that seemed a bit heavy handed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If it is a build system you just run locally, you can easily hardcode the path. If it is something you deploy to various systems, you need to consider the possibility of different `realpath` binaries in your deployment scripts.

Comment: @Allan, I just wanted to use the original realpath i.e. not the one that came in with Ventura. I managed to solve this by adding a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin which comes before /bin. Now, I get the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: There is no original realpath :-)

Comment: Which macOS are you using?  As @nohillside said, there is `realpath`. But to address the question, you just change the order of directories in your PATH variable,

Comment: @allan `/bin/realpath` is a recent addition and doesn't support `-s`. I assume the OP had the GNU version of `realpath` installed via Homebrew but `/bin` early in the path (which worked as long as macOS didn't include its own `realpath`).

Comment: That's right @nohillside. Since Ventura added the macOS realpath to /bin, I ended up just creating a symbolic link to the GNU realpath in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change anything in /bin. Apple now provides the system on a sealed volume.

The correct solution is to fix the build files so that they do not use an non usual argument.

However you can use the $PATH environment variable to find a GNU realpath by installing that program and having its directory on the PATH before Apple's directories.

The easiest way is use a package manager like MacPorts or HomeBrew.

Although read this [SuperUser answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136527/5140) to see that there might not be a common way to fix this as the command line realpath is not standardized at all